# What are all the secret achievements in Paradise Island?

Tags: achievements, paradise-island

In the game [Paradise Island](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.seventeenbullets.android.island) ([Paradise Island: Exotic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paradise-island-exotic/id396958695?mt=8) on iOS), what are all the secret achievements?

Comment: So far the only one I've got is `Hot Dogs Fan` - build 15 hot dog stands, and some of the others seem to follow a similar pattern. No idea about the rest though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I've found a decent list, here are the secret achievements. Note that all of the structures must be on the map at once to gain the award (you can't build 14, demolish one, then build another).

**Hot Dogs Fan**: Build 15 hot dog stands
**Simple Solution fan**: Build 15 cabins
**Trifles Fan**: Build 15 gift shops
**Spa Salons Fan**: Build 10 sunny centers
**Mega Party Goer**: Build 10 disco
**Aristocrat**: Build 3 golf clubs
**Casinos Fan**: Build 5 crystal casinos
**Altitude Lover**: Build 2 galaxy restaurants
**We Remember about the Defender**: Build 2 gold defenders
**Amusement Park**: Build 2 observation wheels
**Great Pyramids**: Build 3 pyramids
**Lord of Excitement**: Build 3 pearl casinos
**Master of Bowling**: Build 3 Bowling clubs
**Following the Montgolfier Brothers**: Build 3 Ballon launch platforms
**The Sun Only**: Have all power generated by solar stations, remove all windmills